# Does Apple provide localized recovery options for common NSButton title's for NSError's?

Tags: cocoa, localization, nserror, nslocalizedstring

Does Apple provide localized strings for common NSButton titles, such as the equivalents to *OK*, *Cancel*, *Try Again*, and *Quit*?

I'm attempting to create a custom NSError object from one handed to me by another Cocoa framework.  I want to implement the `NSErrorRecoveryAttempting` informal protocol to let the user *Try Again* or *Quit* if an error occurs.  For (brief) example:

```
NSString *cachesDir = ...;
NSError  *error     = nil;
BOOL     success    = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachesDir withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

// Failed creating the directory.
if (!success)
{
 NSMutableDictionary *errorUserInfoCopy = [[[error userInfo] mutableCopy] autorelease];

 NSArray *recoveryOptions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Try Again", @"Quit", nil];
 [errorUserInfoCopy setObject:recoveryOptions forKey:NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey];

 NSError *newError = [NSError errorWithDomain:[error domain] code:[error code] userInfo:errorUserInfoCopy];
 [NSApp presentError:newError];
}
```

In line 10, `NSArray *recoveryOptions = ...`, does Apple provide a way to easily get localized versions of Try Again/Quit (among other common NSButton titles)?  Or must I manually populate `.strings` files and use `NSLocalizedString()` instead?

Apple does provide localized recovery options for non-customized NSError's:

```
NSArray *recoveryOptions = [anError localizedRecoverySuggestion];
```

But this usually just defaults to a localized "OK".  It's not suitable for custom `NSErrorRecoveryAttempting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Apple does not.